# Within CUDA kernel, copying from device to host without pinned memory?

Tags: cuda

Is there a way to copy **from device** *to host* **within the kernel**?

Something like the following code:

```
__global__ void kernel(int n, double *devA, double *hostA) {
    double x = 1.0;

    do_computation();

    cudaMemcpy(hostA, &x, sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    do_computation();

    cudaMemcpy(hostA, devA, sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
}
```

Is it possible? Based on the CUDA documentation, the cudaMemcpy is not callable from the device, right?

**NOTE:** I don't want to use the pinned memory. It is low performance since I will constantly check the host variable (memory). So, using pinned memory will issue a page-fault (at best for post-Pascal) that will definitely happen! If both host and device access the same location, it will basically be a ping-pong effect!

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible?

In one word, no.

> Based on the CUDA documentation, the `cudaMemcpy` is not callable from the device, right?

In fact, if you do read the [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#api-reference), you will see that `cudaMemcpy` is supported in device code, but only for device to device transfers and not using local variables as source or destination.

Comment: Thanks @talonmies. Yes. I remember that exception (D2D). Since my focus was on D2H from device, I didn't mention that :-)